# data table multiple check box does not keep selection

Tags: primefaces, datatable, pagination, selection

I'm using datatable with multiple selection and pagination, when I select a row and go to another page and then return to the page I was the row I've selected is not selected anymore. I'm using primefaces 3.5, mojarra, jboss 7.1, my bean is viewScoped. Below is my code:

```xml
<p:dataTable id="boxList" var="box" value="#{protocolBean.boxModel}" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
   selection="#{protocolBean.selectedBoxes}">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            #{label['boxes']}  
        </f:facet>  
   <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:4%" />  
        <p:column>  
            <h:outputText value="#{box.code}"/>  
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{box.selected}" filterOptions="#{protocolBean.selectedOptions}" filterMatchMode="exact">
           <h:outputText value="#{box.selected}"/>
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Model:

```java
public class BoxModel extends ListDataModel<Box> implements SelectableDataModel<Box> {

   public BoxModel() {
   }

   public BoxModel(List<Box> boxes) {
      super(boxes);
   }

   @Override
   public Object getRowKey(Box box) {
      return box.getId();
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   @Override
   public Box getRowData(String rowKey) {
      List<Box> boxes = (List<Box>) getWrappedData();  
        for(Box b : boxes) {  
            if(b.getId().equals(rowKey))  
                return b;  
        }  
        return null;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what was happening, the problem is with my model class, in method getRowData I'm comparing a long (b.getId) with a String (rowKey) this way the method always return null and will never know who is selected.